# Is it possible to turn off radio without turning of wifi on Lenovo k900?

Tags: settings, battery-life, cellular-radio, power-options

I am currently having a look at the power consumption of a lenovo k900 phone and on the hardware side it seems Radio and Screen is using most of the power.

I am planning to use wifi but not the radio. Are they disconnected ? If so, can I use just the wifi, but no radio/telephony ? Are the settings or commands/intents to access these settings ?

Thanks!